# Is there a reliable way to have WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED applied to all queries?

Tags: security, security-review, field-level-security, fls, pmd

I've just gone through a biggish code base making sure that [WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_enforced.htm) is set on every query. Most were, but for some recent additions, it hadn't been included. For managed packages that need to go through security reviews, this is a great way to respect object and field level security on reads. But tedious to manually check big code bases, especially where dynamic SOQL is used.

- Does anyone have a [PMD Apex Security Rule](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_security.html) created for this that they would be happy to share?
- IMHO it would be great if `WITH` became the default mode at say API 55 with a `WITHOUT SECURITY_ENFORCED` option also provided. (Or some other mechanism used to turn `WITH` on everywhere.)

Comment: For the latter, make sure you submit an idea on the Idea Exchange. I'm sure @ca_peterson would love to hear it.

Comment: There is something to be said for making people explicitly type out `WITHOUT SECURITY_ENFORCED`. It's secure be default unless you type out something that fills people with dread and sets off all sorts of alarm bells. Can you can easily search the code base for instances bypassing security.

Comment: For dynamic SOQL, *Reliably* detecting SOQL-keywords is an unsolved research problem. Think of all the textual transformations that are possible and what kind of SMT solver you would need to resolve variables at runtime. However you can find many instances with a regular grep. Tools like PMD, which don't have a string solver built in, are not going to do much better than grep in this case.  If it is not dynamic soql but an actual keyword, then you can reliably detect it, but I think you would need to write a custom rule for it.

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger, Agree you can search to find missing ones, but would like some approach that detects that on commit as hard to get all developers and reviewers to be perfect.

Comment: Hi @RobertSussland, I see that PMD does use an abstract syntax tree, based on https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/tree/develop/packages/salesforcedx-vscode-apex. Don't know how reliable this all is overall, but likely to do a better job than simpler patter matching.

Comment: The AST is for parsing apex. How does that help you with runtime resolution of variables?  Think about whether this query has "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED" as a modifer and how an AST could help you answer that question: Database.query("SELECT"  + fieldlist + "FROM Contacts " + getModifiers(fieldList) );  String getModifiers(fieldList) { ... if x != "foo__c" return "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED" else return ""} These are what typical dynamic SOQL queries look like, and you are basically talking about introducing string solvers (SMT problem). That is why people end up just running greps

Comment: Hi @RobertSussland, Thanks starting to get it now. Was looking at a lot of `Variable 'xxx' defined but not used` items today that are variables bound into the dynamic SOQL string; similar challenge for tooling.

Comment: Right! Doing static analysis on Dynamic SOQL (or Type.forName() ) is equivalent to doing static analysis on eval().  Really it's best to ban dynamic constructions if you want code that is comprehensible to tooling (as well as human reviewers). Having rules in place that force developers to write code that allows for efficient reasoning is the secret to secure coding, and flagging violations of these rules is how you deliver secure code without being able to solve the Halting problem.